# Disable Android Studio warning: "Access can be ..."

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

After an update of Android Studio I get warnings on fields like:

```
public int ex1 = 0;
int ex2 = 0;
```

or methods or nested classes
when they are used only in one class or in the package:

"Access can be private" or "Access can be package-only"

This is can be, and I don't want these warnings but I cannot find how I can deactivate them. Any ideas?

Comment: But isn't that a good thing to follow ?

Comment: Not really. If access can be private but I set it to public I may want to use it public later.

Comment: writing code for future cases that do not yet exist will lead to unnecessarily complicated code

Comment: Consider you have a method: You call it when the app is opened and during the life-time of the app. The internal call is added, but the external class is yet not added. You still need the class and the method, but want to keep access to public so you don't need to change that later. In those cases, these warnings are in the way, and the code is necessary, but will have more calls in the future from external and internal sources

Comment: @ChintanSoni Not when it gets it wrong!

Comment: I would also add that one may be making a library and the method needs to be public. When you are creating just your library code and unit tests, package private will suffice. So its good to turn off those warnings to better expose warnings that may be important

Comment: I'm getting this even when the member data is accessed outside the class!  Anyone else?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

In Android Studio 2.2.1 open Settings-> Editor -> Inspections. Now go to Java->Declaration redundancy->Declaration Access Can be Weaker and uncheck this option.

Comment: In this case I like to keep the warning but as a weaker one. I set this inspection it to *weak warning* and... edit the weaker warning severity so it doesn't show the *error stripe mark* on the right side, which is distracting. Hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 63):

You can also put [this annotation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html) on top of your class:

```
@SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess")
```

Comment: While that is possible, that annotation would have to be added in **every single file** - And it has to be added. It is a valid answer so I upvoted, but this is really tedious if I had to write that annotation in every java file. Changing settings is still the easiest solution (for me)

Comment: Ah, it worked better for me, because I only wanted to turn it off certain data classes.

Comment: It depends on usage. This works too, and is handy if you want it for just a few classes (it is a valid answer, and it does work). I upvoted because this answer still works, but for my usage it is better to disable globally.

Comment: This is also a better solution for my use where I *do* want to be warned about access but want to override the warnings for specific methods. Note that the annotation can also be applied at the method level not just the class level.

Answer (score 4):

All you have to do is disable the inspection that fires this warning.
Taken from ["Suppression Inspections" page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/suppressing-inspections.html) in IntelliJ help:

To suppress an inspection in the editor

1. Set the cursor to the highlighted code issue in the editor.
2. Press ⌥⏎ or click the light bulb icon to expand the suggestion
   list.
3. Depending on the issue, you will see either quick-fixes related to
   the inspection or the Inspection `<inspection name>` options item.
4. Use the up/down arrow keys to select this item and then press the
   right arrow key or just click the right arrow next to this item.
5. Pressing the left arrow key, or ⎋ hides the suggestion list.
   In the inspection options list, select the desired suppress action

   The inspection will be suppressed with special comments in the
   corresponding piece of code.