# How to hide Android Studio's "Property could be private" inspection?

Tags: android, android-studio

I would like to hide Android Studio's **"Property could be private" inspection** in my code.

So far I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41237196/disable-android-studio-warning-access-can-be) but **none of the solutions listed there worked for me.**

`@SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess")` Did absolutely nothing for me.

### The settings mentioned in the other post already turned off and does nothing as well:

[image]

### And it seems this option also missing the quick hide method which is also described in that post:

[image]

### Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Your first screenshot shows you modifying a Java inspection. Your second screenshot shows Kotlin code. If your code is Kotlin, you might want to look at Kotlin inspections.

Comment: Well true. But also I don't find the same setting in Kotlin for the love of God.